# Could not login to azure instance created using a managed data disk

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I created a virtual machine using the following command in azure cli.

```
az vm create --resource-group Test_Group --location eastus --name myVM2 --os-type linux --attach-os-disk disk1
```

I installed grub on disk1 and all necessary things for booting.I am facing an issue in connecting to the instance using ssh.

Comment: What is the error you get? Please specify your question.

Comment: There is no error but when I use ssh IpAddress it does not connect and when i use ssh -vvv Ipaddress in debug screen it shows host unreachable when the vm is already on.

Comment: Check serial logs to see the state of the OS.

Comment: I will try to check logs and post it Thanks